# Update only kubernetes under OKD ( OpenShift )

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, okd

Latest OKD (OpenShift) version is 3.11 and it is using an older version ( 1.11 ) of Kubernetes. Is it possible to update underlying Kubernetes version to latest without upgrading ( It is not possible ) or effecting the OKD ?